Prisma client : the provided database credentials for `(not available)` are not valid
I am using prisma version 5.17.0 in my Nextjs application.
When using the prisma studio using npx prisma studio the database is authenticated and connected successfully and I can see the usage on the database cluster too. But the when I use prisma client I get error as

PrismaClientInitializationError:
Invalid prisma.user.findUnique() invocation:
Authentication failed against database server at ..., the provided database credentials for (not available) are not valid.
Please make sure to provide valid database credentials for the database server at ...

I have initialized prisma client as per the official docs for nextjs by prisma-docs
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const prismaClientSingleton = () => {
  return new PrismaClient()
}

const prisma = globalThis.prismaGlobal ?? prismaClientSingleton()

export default prisma

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') globalThis.prismaGlobal = prisma


My minimal home page looks like this
export default function Home() {
    const { data: session, status } = useSession();

    useEffect(() => {
      async function checkDetails() {
        if (status === 'authenticated') {
          const response = await fetch('/api/user/check', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ userId: session.user.id }),
          })
          if (!response.ok) {
            console.log("No record found")
          }
          else{
            console.log("user id found")
          }
        }
      }
      checkDetails();
      }, [status, session]);
    
      if (status === 'loading') {
        return <p>Loading...</p>;
      }

      if (status === 'unauthenticated') {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>You are not signed in</p>
            <button className="" onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>
          </div>
        );
      } 

  return (
    <div>
      <Posts/>
      <p>Signed in as {session.user.email}</p>
      <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
    </div>
  );
}


The route handler at /api/user/check looks like this
import prisma from "@/app/PrismaClient/db";

export async function POST(request) {
    const { userId } = await request.json()
    console.log("user id", userId);
  
    try {
      const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
          userId: userId,
        },
      })
  
      if (!user) {
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: 'User not found' }), { status: 404 })
      }
  
      return new Response(JSON.stringify(user), { status: 200 })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: 'Internal server error' }), { status: 500 })
    }
  }

and finally my schema.prisma looks like this
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "cockroachdb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

models...

I have checked all the migrations were properly applied. Are there more steps to be done to set up the prisma client?
